# Conditional Formatting from external condition Python Dash

Tags: python, dataframe, datatable, plotly-dash, styling

I am working on a dash project and I am actually facing a problem.

I have 2 data frames with the same column names, the same index and one common column (same rows).

I only display one of the 2 data frames on my dash but I would like to use the other one to format the style of the one that is displayed.
And for now it seems that with style_data_conditional I can only style the cells with elements that are inside of the current data frame.

Does someone know how to do it ?
Thanks in advance !

Example to help if I am not clear:
I have prices in the shown data frame and an indicator (between -1 and 1) about each price in a second data frame. The point is to color in red the datas associated to an indicator such as abs(indicator) > 9

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution but I'll let this question open for those who would have the same problem than I do. I have not found a beautiful way to do it but the best for me was to create a dataframe of colors (I'll show you) and associate each value to it in style_data_conditional.

Here the example :

```
style_data_conditional = [{
                             'if': {'row_index': i, 'column_id': j},
                             'backgroundColor': colors_df.loc[i, j]
                          }
                          for i in range(db.shape[0]) for j in db.columns
                         ]
```

with colors_df looking like this :

```
       Column1  Column2  Column3

0      #fffff   #fffff   #fffff
1      #fffff   #fffff   #cbe26
2      #cbe26   #fffff   #cbe26
3      #fffff   #fffff   #cbe26
```